# Angular2: Uncaught (in promise): Quotes are not supported for evaluation! in the component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which has an input parameter:

```js
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'comment' ,
    template: `    
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <div class="post-owner">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                          <img class="media-object rounder" src=imageURI >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
})

export class CommentCompoent{
    @Input() imageURI="";
}
```

And in the parent component I have passed a image path to it like this:

```html
<comment [imageURI]='image_path'></comment>
```

The problem is, when I run it, it complains with:

> `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Quotes are not supported for evaluation!`

So what should I do?

**Update:** It works fine when I remove `[imageURI]='image_path'` in the parent component, and it shows the rest of component perfectly

Comment: Don't you get a hint about line and column in the template where the error is caused?

Comment: Maybe caused by the typo in `CommentCompoent` (`poent` instead of `ponent`)? Do you import this component somewhere or list it in `directives: [...]` with a different name?

Comment: Maybe caused by an issue in the parent component?

Comment: Also, `src=imageURI` should be `src="imageURI"` and I would use double quotes everywhere: `<comment [imageURI]="image_path"></comment>`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should change your `comment` tag in the parent component to this:

```html
<comment [imageURI]="image_path"></comment>
```

Don't use single quotes when assigning a template binding. Only use them to format strings, like this:

```html
<comment [imageURI]="'path/to/image.jpg'"></comment>
```

Answer (score 20):

Anyone googling this error: the error contains no useful information and could be thrown for many different reasons so in my case it was impossible to figure out by just looking at the HTML. However if you put a breakpoint in the angular file loaded in your browser (in my case `compiler.umd.js`, line 11702, see [expression_converter.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.ts#L395) in the `@angular/compiler` module, line 395, function `visitQuote()` which is what throws the exception) you can drill into the `ast` parameter which has properties called `location` and `uninterpretedExpression` that help you narrow down which component and expression are causing this. In my case it was missing curly braces around an `ngClass` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this was a lifesaver!

Comment: My issue was similar...an extract caret `>` in the html :?

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer. It comes back to my parent component:
The right format is

```html
<comment [imageURI]=image_path></comment>
```

```js
export class SinglePictureComponent{
    username='Salman kkk';
    profile_pic="https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13743117_1060048037418472_411027981_a.jpg";
    comment="I love you";
}
```

and then set the property is:

```html
 <comment [username]=username   [comment]=comment [imageURI]=profile_pic></comment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same error, like this:

[image]

The error-proned html code was:

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="value">{{action.progress}}</span>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="bar" style="{{width:action.progress}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

fixed code: the solution below worked for me. Action is coming from `.ts` file as style should be `[ngStyle]` so we can directly pass item value.

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="value">{{action.progress}}</span>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="bar" [ngStyle]="{width:action.progress}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```